# GStreamer on Android linking omxgoogleh264encoder to mp4mux fails

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am trying to use "amcvidenc-omxgoogleh264encoder" or "amcvidenc-c2androidh264encoder" encoders on Android.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
udpsrc port=9005 ! application/x-rtp-stream,encoding-name=H265 ! queue ! \ 
rtpstreamdepay ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! amcviddec-omxgooglehevcdecoder ! queue ! amcvidenc-omxgoogleh264encoder ! \
mp4mux ! filesink name=fileSink location=test.mp4
```

this throws:

```
could not link amcvidenc-omxgoogleh264encoder0 to mp4mux0
```

There is absolutely no documentation for OMX or C2 decoders/encoders online, I would appriciate if someone can send a link to the documentations or the source code of these encoders.

Answer (score 0):

It needs `h264parse` element between encoder and the mp4mux.